# Does Linq to SQL designer support foreign keys with compound primary keys?

Tags: .net, linq-to-sql

The linq to sql designer is not generating the property for one of the associations of my model, the only difference between this association and other associations is that this one references a 5 column primary key, could this be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that one of the tables in the relationship didn't have a primary key.